# How to implement OAUTH 2.0 to access Google Analytics

Tags: c#, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I've Read that Google discontinued the previous authentication method to access Google API, so now we have to use that OAuth2 Authentication method. I've read that we have to go to the Developer console and get the ClientID and Client Secret so that we can perform the authentication. But I'm having big troubles to code the necessary changes to successfully Login.

I'm Searching for guidelines to do the changes at the login level. I tried to apply some code I found on the web, but I wasn't successful. About the Developer Console I already have a Project with the ClientID and Secret so I didn't generated a new one but used the ClientID and Secret already generated.

**This is the working code, before google change:**

```
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for GoogleAnalytics
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class GoogleAnalytics : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetAnalyticsPageViews()
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;

            object cacheObjPageViewsCount = CacheService.Get(CacheService.ANALYTICSPAGEVIEWS);

            if (cacheObjPageViewsCount != null)
                returnValue = cacheObjPageViewsCount as string;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string userName = Configurations.GetConfigurationValueAsString("GoogleAnalyticsUsername");
                    string passWord = Configurations.GetConfigurationValueAsString("GoogleAnalyticsPassword");
                    string profileId = Configurations.GetConfigurationValueAsString("GoogleAnalyticsProfileId");

                    const string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data";

                    AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("ApplicationName");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    {
                        service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);
                    }

                    DataQuery query1 = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);
                    query1.Ids = "ga:" + profileId;
                    query1.Metrics = "ga:visits";
                    query1.Sort = "ga:visits";
                    query1.GAStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    query1.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    query1.StartIndex = 1;
                    DataFeed dataFeedVisits = service.Query(query1);
                    DataEntry dataEntry = (DataEntry)dataFeedVisits.Entries[0];
                    returnValue = dataEntry.Metrics[0].Value;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    LogService.LogException(exc);
                    returnValue = string.Empty;
                }

                CacheService.Add(CacheService.PP_ANALYTICSPAGEVIEWS_COUNT_CACHE_KEY, returnValue);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the changes that I tried to perform**

Instead of using if "service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);"
I use "GoogleOAutho2.authenticate();"
the result of this is that it's open a new page with this error: The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:60279/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI.

I didnt understand why im send to a new page, this didnt happen with the previous authentication method, Where am I missing?

Thanks in Advance,
N

The page that I'm sended to:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=**clientid**&redirect_uri=http://localhost:60279/authorize/&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly

(this code is base on [this samples](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

namespace GoogleOAuth2 { 

class GoogleOAutho2
{

    static string[] scopes = new string[] {
        AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics,  // view and manage your Google Analytics data
        AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit,  // Edit and manage Google Analytics Account
        AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,   // Edit and manage Google Analytics Users
        AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly};     // View Google Analytics Data

    static String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENTID"; // found in Developer console
    static String CLIENT_SECRET = "SECRET";// found in Developer console
    // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%


    public static bool authenticate()
    {

        try
        {
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = CLIENT_ID, ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET }, scopes, Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("XXX.GoogleAnalytics.Auth.Store")).Result;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exeption)
        {
            string error = exeption.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help.  I am not using these same classes, and not even C#.  The approach I use is straight http calls.  In my implementation I call **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth** passing as the **redirect_uri** parameter the same value specified in the API contsole (see screen shot).

Is this being passed/specified anywhere?[image]

Comment: Hello M Schenkel, thanks for the response! My redirect uri is like yours but i didnt get what you mean with calling https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth. Is is possible to not be prompt with that page? I just want to authenticate and get the visits (now sessions) of the site.

Comment: Sounds like we have different implementations/goals.  The way oAuth works, or at least the way I am doing it, it to have the user "Authenticate".  Google then provides you with a "Refresh Token".  You use this token to get a "short lived" session that lasts 60 minutes.  You use this token in your calls.  After 60 minutes, however, you have to get a new token.  It sounds like you want a solution where on each session user is prompted to enter credentials.  With oAuth, this only needs to be done once.

Comment: Hello M Schenkel, What I want is to use one acount to display the number of visits in my site. only this. so I don't want the user to be prompt with credentials even once. this is possible with OAuth2? is this the correct Way?

Comment: Yes it is.  When you said _just want to authenticate and get the visits (now sessions) of the site_ it sounded like your implementation would prompt for authentication on each session.  oAuth2 is the way to go.  But you will need to store the refresh token.  And, somewhere along the way you will have to authenticate against Google to do this (only once though).

Comment: Hello M Schenkel! I Finally managed to succeed. I Achieve it with the Service Account Authentication. and the creation of an Client ID of type Service Account . I used the P12 generated from this Service Account to authenticate and use the GA API. Looks like the sessions does not need OAuth2. Thanks for your time! Best Regards